# The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'pickImage'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a stateful widget,but keep getting red line under my setState method with this error:

```
The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'pickImage'.
```

My Flutter Version:

```
Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable
```

ImagePicker Package Version:

```
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
```

This is the code:

```
class pickImage extends StatefulWidget {

  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {  //Keep getting red line here(under setState)
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  _pickImageState createState() => _pickImageState();
}

class _pickImageState extends State<pickImage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      
    );
  }
}
```

I have googled this issue, but still can't find an appropriate answer, that's why came here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `getImage` inside `_pickImageState`.

The setState method is a member of the State class. Not the StatefulWidget class.

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Comment: But why isn't it not supported there?

Comment: @BilalSaeed Because ```setState``` is function that is written in ```State``` class. and ```_pickImageState``` extends ```State```, so only this class can call ```setState```.

Answer (score 1):

The `setState` method ([see documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)) is a member of the `State<T>` class. *Not* the `StatefulWidget` class.

That means you can call it in classes derived from `State<T>` like your `_pickImageState`, but not in classes that are not. Like your class `pickImage`, where you are trying to call your function new.

You should be able to move the whole `getImage` method into your `_pickImageState` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create setState on `pickImage` class your move your setState methode to `_pickImageState`

```
   class pickImage extends StatefulWidget {
 pickImage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  _pickImageState createState() => _pickImageState();
}

class _pickImageState extends State<pickImage> {
 final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {  //Keep getting red line here(under setState)
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      
    );
  }
}
```