# Change icon after click in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have code:

```
class SoundIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  bool soundIsAvailable;
  SoundIcon(this.soundIsAvailable);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          soundIsAvailable ? "assets/graphics/sound_on.svg" : "assets/graphics/sound_off.svg",
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        tooltip: 'Set sound',
        onPressed: () {
          setSoundStatus(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void setSoundStatus(BuildContext context) {
    final level1Cubit = context.read<Level1Cubit>();
    level1Cubit.setSoundStatus();
  }
}
```

What I need to do to change icon after click, because now it works only when screen refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you have to use the `setState` method, so the UI can refresh.

Please note that the setState method is a member of the State class. Not the StatefulWidget class. See [The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'pickImage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67086063/the-method-setstate-isnt-defined-for-the-type-pickimage) for more on this.

Here is what your code should look like IMO :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SoundIcon extends StatefulWidget {

  bool soundIsAvailable;
  SoundIcon({Key key, this.soundIsAvailable}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SoundIconState createState() => _SoundIconState();
}

class _SoundIconState extends State<SoundIcon> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          widget.soundIsAvailable ? "assets/graphics/sound_on.svg" : "assets/graphics/sound_off.svg",
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        tooltip: 'Set sound',
        onPressed: () {
//you have to use a setState to perform a relaunch of the UI
          setState(() {
            widget.soundIsAvailable = true;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'SoundIcon'.

Comment: just edited the answer, note that a shortcut to create a StatefulWidget + the State class is typing "stful" then press enter when the autocomplete shows